# Double Thresholding with opencv

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, threshold

I'm writing code using visual c++ with opencv libraries. Can I do a double threshold on a grey image (like a band pass)? For example I want to set at MaxValue all the level between 100 and 176 and at Zero all the remaining values. Is it possible with opencv?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange):

```
cv::inRange(src, cv::Scalar(100), cv::Scalar(176), dst);
```